# Usage of "hundred" colloquially in numbers

Tags: grammatical-number, numbers

I want to know when it is valid to say **2 digit** + **"hundred"**.
Suppose we have the number **3,500**, then some people might say:
    -> thirty-five hundred
So for a 4 digit number which is not **1,000**, people might say **2 digit** + **"hundred"** colloquially.

What happens if the number is **3,500,000,000**. Is the following usage of **"hundred"** valid?
    -> thirty-five hundred million
Or if the number is **1,003,500**. Is the following usage of **"hundred"** valid?
    -> one million thirty-five hundred

Thank you in advance.

Comment: it's mainly Americans who say "thirty five hundred" for 3,500. Brits usually say " three thousand five hundred". Also most people on either side of the Atlantic would say "three and a half billion" or "three point five billion" for 3,500,000,000.

Comment: I've heard just about every possible wording, but your last two examples would not be idiomatic in the US.

Comment: For you last example, it would depend on whether the 3500 is significant. Thirty-five hundred is a small part of a million.  If the significance lies only in the amount slightly exceeding a reference point (such as a million dollars) people use expressions like “just north of a million” or “a million and change”. On the other hand, sometimes we want to emphasize the smallness by giving the number precisely, e.g. “He went in with a million. Two years later, he sold out for a million and thirty-five hundred.” In general, however, ninety-nine hundred is as high as you can go.

Comment: Thank you for your replies.
From all of your comments, I now understand that such usage (i.e. "thirty-five hundred million" and "one million thirty-five hundred") is not common. Also thank you for making me aware of the fact that people say "three and a half billion" for **3,500,000,000** .